# How do I access this javascript object?

Tags: javascript, object, hash, associative

```
{"profit_center" : 

{"branches":

[

{"branch":      {"work_order":"1","cutover":"1","site_survey":"1","branch_number":"3310","quote":"1","configuration":"1","purchase_order":"1","hardware_swap":"1"}},

{"branch":{"work_order":"1","cutover":"1","site_survey":"1","branch_number":"3311","quote":"1","configuration":"1","purchase_order":"1","hardware_swap":"1"}},

{"branch":{"work_order":"1","cutover":"0","site_survey":"1","branch_number":"3312","quote":"1","configuration":"1","purchase_order":"1","hardware_swap":"1"}},

{"branch":{"work_order":"1","cutover":"1","site_survey":"1","branch_number":"3313","quote":"1","configuration":"1","purchase_order":"1","hardware_swap":"1"}},

{"branch":{"work_order":"1","cutover":"0","site_survey":"1","branch_number":"3314","quote":"1","configuration":"1","purchase_order":"1","hardware_swap":"1"}},

{"branch":{"work_order":"1","cutover":"1","site_survey":"1","branch_number":"3315","quote":"1","configuration":"1","purchase_order":"1","hardware_swap":"1"}}

],


"profit_center_name":"Alabama"}}
```

I tried accessing it in ajax through this,

```
data.profit_center //data here is the ajax variable e.g. function(data)
```

or through this `data["profit_center"]`

but no luck

How do I access this javascript object properly. ?

By the way that code above is from `console.log(data)`

EDIT:

Result from `console.log(data.profit_center)` and `console.log(data["profit_center"])` is undefined

Comment: What do you need to access exactly?

Comment: everything, access anything there so i can get an idea how

Comment: Make sure that data is not `null`. Does the console give any messages when you try to execute that javascript?

Comment: that code i posted is from console.log(data). so it is not null

Answer (score 0):

First parse your data if you've not already done so.

You can access, for example, each `branch_number` like so:

```
var branches = data.profit_center.branches;

for (var i = 0, l = branches.length; i < l; i++) {
  console.log(branches[i].branch.branch_number);
}
```

In summary, `profit_center` is an object and `branches` is an array of objects. Each element in the array contains a branch object that contains a number of keys. Loop over the `branches` array and for each element access the branch object inside using the key names to get the values.

The profit center name can be found by accessing the `profit_center_name` key on the `profit_center` object:

```
console.log(data.profit_center.profit_center_name); // Alabama
```

You could even use the new functional array methods to interrogate the data and pull out only those branches you need. Here I use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to pull those objects where the `purchase_order` is equal to `2`. Note that the numeric values in your JSON are strings, not integers.

```
var purchaseOrder2 = branches.filter(function (el) {
  return el.branch.purchase_order === '2';
});
```

[**DEMO for the three examples**](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/P9z7Q/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `data`in a variable like

`var json = data`

and you can access `profit_center` like

`alert(json.profit_center);`

`alert(json.profit_center.profit_center_name); //Alabama`

`for(var i =0 ;i<json.profit_center.branches.length;i++){
    alert(json.profit_center.branches[i]);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have found out why it is undefined, It is a json object so I need to parse it before i can access it like a javascript object.

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);
```

Then that's it.